# How to set reply to email when send mail from Outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am employee of XYZ company. I have outlook configure with XYZ company mail.

When I send mail from my Outlook and when some one reply on that mail, it goes to `abc@XYZ.com` instead of that, I want to get reply on `abc@gmail.com`.

I want to know that, is there any way to set reply to email address when send mail from Outlook 2013? Like extra field in send dialog etc..

Comment: There are literally *thousands* of hits in [google](http://bfy.tw/4Xdc) for that question. If you had spent some time looking in your account settings, you'd have either found the setting yourself, or with your first hit in google.

Comment: I tried google, but I didn't get any help from there, Is that possible, my admin hide this functionality ?

Comment: Well, in an Exchange-environment (which I suppose you're in), this can't be generally set by users. You can, however, change it in each mail you're composing. In the ribbon bar check: *Options - direct replies to*

Answer (score 1):

I suppose my comment should be an answer.

In an Exchange-environment (which I suppose you're in), this can't be generally set by users. You can, however, change it in each mail you're composing. In the ribbon bar check: `Options - direct replies to`.